# Template works on normal webserver but not in Centos

Tags: php, templates, centos, webserver, hosting

i own 2 websites, one points to my vps and one doesn't(it's hosted on shared hosting). I recently downloaded a template from the internet but it has a problem. Not the template but my vps has a problem.

The website that is hosted in a shared hosting: 
http://shqipefl.com (The template works perfectly, try clicking "Forum" in menu.

The website that is pointing to my vps which runs centos 6 x64 bit
http://genius-host.eu (The template doesn't work, try clicking "Forum" in menu.

Can you guys please tell me what/where the problem can be? Thanks in advance.